# Are there processes to standardize the shape of a crystal during crystallization?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, crystal-structure

I am trying to standardize the shape of europium dibenzoylmethide triethylammonium (EuD4TEA) during its crystallization process. I'm a mechanical engineering student and am not too familiar on the details of crystallization. Is there a process for creating crystals of standard size, shape, and weight? If so, would the process vary between what I am using and any other type of crystal?

Comment: All you can do is to try to create reproducible conditions. Crystals can generally take a multitude of shapes based on all sorts of factors - concentration, temperature, pressure, flow rates, other stuff in solution and so on.

Comment: First of all, please specify what size of crystals you are interested in: micrometer size? Centimeter? Smaller crystals with uniform size are much easier to achieve than large ones.

Comment: Thanks @MaxW! @vapid I'm interested more in centimeter/millimeter sized crystals.